# Safari won't let font sizes get bigger than 9px, computed styles always smaller than stylesheet

Tags: html, css, safari

I am having a weird problem with developing a mobile site on the Safari simulator in xCode and debugging in Safari's inspector. The font sizes are always specified as 20, or sometimes 25 px, but the computed styles are always around 9px or some weird fraction like 8.345624px. I cant figure out where this is coming from. Below is a picture of all the styles being applied to that p tag from my stylesheet, and the computed styles below. I cannot fathom why Safari is doing this.

EDIT: few more details. The font size will magically be accurate if I make it 29 or 30px. But anything after 20px just gets computed down to 9px. Chrome does not repro this problem.

The HTML: I am speaking of the `signup-label` class

```
<div class="ios-account-details-2 slide-group">
        <p class="signup-label">What's your birthday?</p>
        <div class="birthday-flexWrapper">
            <select class='newUserBirthMonth'>
                <option disabled selected>Month</option>
                <option value='January'>January</option>
                <option value='February'>February</option>
                <option value='March'>March</option>
                <option value='April'>April</option>
                <option value='May'>May</option>
                <option value='June'>June</option>
                <option value='July'>July</option>
                <option value='August'>August</option>
                <option value='September'>September</option>
                <option value='October'>October</option>
                <option value='November'>November</option>
                <option value='December'>December</option>
            </select>
            <input class='completeProfileField birthDayField' maxlength="2" placeholder="DD" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='DD'"></input>
            <input class='completeProfileField birthYearField' maxlength="4" placeholder="YYYY" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder='YYYY'"></input>
        </div>
        <p class="signup-label">What's your gender?</p>
        <select class='newUserGender'>  
            <option disabled selected>Gender</option>
            <option value='2'>Female</option>
            <option value='1'>Male</option>
            <option value='3'>Custom</option>
        </select>
        <input class='newUserGenderMore completeProfileField' style='display: none;' placeholder='Custom'/>  

        <button class='login-next login-button red-gradient completeSignUp normalLogin' id="completeSignUpButton" disabled style="border-radius: 3px;">Complete Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

[image: My stylesheet/user rules]

[image: The computed styles]

Comment: Can you post your code and give us a [mcve] please?

Comment: @MichaelCoker What is there to see? My stylesheets?